# Stuck in generating the right LEFT join queries with count using the Sequelize models in the nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize in my NodeJS app with Postgres as database. Following is my correct SQL query which gives me right set of data while running them on database server :-

```
SELECT 
   "expertises"."uuid" AS "id",
   "expertises"."display_name" AS "name",
   "expertises"."modified_by" AS "modifiedBy",
   (
    SELECT COUNT(expertise_uuid)
    FROM expertise_endorsements
    WHERE expertise_uuid = "expertises"."uuid"
   ) AS "users"
FROM "expertises" AS "expertises" 
LEFT JOIN "expertise_endorsements" AS "expertise_endorsements"
ON "expertise_endorsements"."expertise_uuid" = "expertises"."uuid"
LIMIT '16' OFFSET '1';
```

However when I run the app, the ORM is generating the wrong SQL query without any count (as shown below):-

```
SELECT
   "expertises".*,
   "expertise_endorsements"."id" AS "expertise_endorsements.id",
   "expertise_endorsements"."expertise_uuid" AS "expertise_endorsements.expertise_uuid" 
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         "expertises"."id",
         "expertises"."uuid" AS "id",
         "expertises"."display_name" AS "name",
         "expertises"."modified_by" AS "modifiedBy",
         "expertises"."uuid" 
      FROM
         "expertises" AS "expertises" 
      ORDER BY
         "expertises"."name" DESC LIMIT '16' OFFSET '1'
   )
   AS "expertises" 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      "expertise_endorsements" AS "expertise_endorsements" 
      ON "expertises"."uuid" = "expertise_endorsements"."expertise_uuid" 
ORDER BY
   "expertises"."name" DESC;
```

This is my model association :-

```
const consts = require("../services/static/constants");
const Expertises = require("./models/expertises.model");
const ExpertisesEndorsees = require("./models/expertises_endorsees.model");
const ExpertisesEndorsements = require("./models/expertise_endorsements.model");

exports.setAssociations = (db, Sequelize, type) => {
    const expertisesModel = Expertises(db, Sequelize);
    const expertisesEndorseesModel = ExpertisesEndorsees(db, Sequelize);
    const expertisesEndorsementsModel = ExpertisesEndorsements(db, Sequelize);

    expertisesModel.hasMany(expertisesEndorsementsModel, { sourceKey: consts.uuidField, foreignKey: consts.expertiseUuid,  as: consts.modelAliases.EXPERTISE_ENDORSEMENTS });
    expertisesEndorsementsModel.belongsTo(expertisesModel, { foreignKey: consts.uuidField, as: consts.modelAliases.EXPERTISE_ENDORSEMENTS });
    
    return { expertisesModel, expertisesEndorseesModel, expertisesEndorsementsModel };
  
};
```

My logic is below. I'm stuck in understanding and applying the count properly using the Sequelize:-

```
const models = dbUtils.setAssociations(db, consts.getExpertiseFlow);
    const includesData = [
        {
            model: models.expertisesEndorsementsModel,
            attributes: [consts.expertiseUuid],
            // attributes: [
            //  sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col(`${consts.modelAliases.EXPERTISE_ENDORSEMENTS}.${consts.get_endorsee_uuid}`)), "users"
            // ],
            as: consts.modelAliases.EXPERTISE_ENDORSEMENTS,
            required: false
        }
    ];

    let {count: expertiseCount, rows: expertises} = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( 
        await manageExpertise.getSortedExpertises(models, consts.get_expertises, pageOffset, pageLimit, orderBy, includesData, false)));
```

Method:-

```
exports.getSortedExpertises = (models, attributes, offset, limit, orderBy, includes, raw=true) => {
    return models.expertisesModel
        .findAndCountAll({
            attributes,
            include: includes,
            offset: offset,
            limit: limit,
            //order: orderBy,
            raw
        }).then(data => {
            return data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            throw err;
        });
};
```

Would really appreciate if you can assist me in resolving this issue and let me know the root cause. Thank you

Comment: `findAndCountAll` execute 2 queries 1 for count and 1 for find. Could you check if you see another SQL query executed around the SELECT SQL you posted?

Comment: @Emma, yes, I see another for count which is coming like this SELECT
   count("expertises"."id") AS "count" 
FROM
   "expertises" AS "expertises" 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      "expertise_endorsements" AS "expertise_endorsements" 
      ON "expertises"."uuid" = "expertise_endorsements"."expertise_uuid";

Comment: Good. `findAndCountAll` executes 2 queries independently and returns both query results as `{ "count": XXX, "rows": [ ... ] }`, where `count` is the result from the `SELECT count` query and `rows` is the result from the other SELECT query. So `count` won't be a part of result in "rows".  It still looks like result is off because the sequelize is doing SubQuery while your original don't.  Could you try adding `subQuery: false` in `findAndCountAll` and show me what SQL is outputted from sequelize?